# JS.elseif (audio2.play()) { audio2.muted}

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm new to programming in JS and don't understand why this statement is not working.

```js
    <script>
  var audio2 = document.getElementById('audioson2');
  function play2(){
  if (audio2.muted){
  audio2.play()
  } 
  elseif(audio2.play()){
  audio2.muted
  } 
  elseif(!audio2.play()){
  audio2.play()
  }
</script>
```

Any help will be really cool. tks by advance.

Comment: What is `audio2.muted` supposed to do?

Comment: the logic here is : 1-  when audio is muted play the song 2- when the song is played mute it 3- when the song is not play play it . All with one click.

Comment: Hi Hao73, thank you for your answer. What specifically is not working? What is the expected result? Are any exceptions thrown? Please update your question to provide more information.

Comment: Hello Connor, sorry for late update. 139 Uncaught ReferenceError: play2 is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):139). It should play the sound when clicked then mute it if reclicked and demute it it clicked a third time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function play2(){
     
 audio2.play();
 
 audio2.muted=!audio2.muted;
 
 }
```

I did this and work not perfectly but work. Thanks